# Is there a polynomial algorithm which for each graph G and each value k determines whether all the cliques of G have size smaller than k?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, polynomial-time, clique

Is there a polynomial algorithm which for each graph G and each value k determines whether all the cliques of G have size smaller than k?
Is it correct to say that it doesn't exist because clique is NP-Complete?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a polynomial algorithm which for each graph G and each value k determines whether all the cliques of G have size smaller than k?

We do not know the answer to this question.

> Is it correct to say that it doesn't exist because clique is NP-Complete?

No, that would not be correct.  Since we currently do not know whether P=NP, it could be that Clique is polynomial time solvable.

However, if we assume that P != NP, there is no polynomial time algorithm for Clique.

---

Ps: Your problem is in fact co-NP-complete.

Answer (score 0):

If there exists such a polynomial algorithm, then we can run this algorithm for each $k=1,2,...n$ thus a polynomial algorithm with an additional factor $n$ for clique problem is generated. This is a contradiction to the fact that clique is NP-Complete (a direct reduction from independent set can proof the hardness).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you consider a polynomial-time algorithm in this case.

Given a graph and an integer $k$ you can determine if there all the cliques are of size at most $k$ by looking at all sets of $(k+1)$ vertices and determining if they form a clique. If there is any clique of size larger than $k$, then choosing any $(k+1)$ of those nodes will form a clique.

So you can answer your question in $O(n^{k+1})$ time. Is that polynomial? Depends on your framework.

Comment: This is quite a stretch. If your algorithm, $A(G,k)$ is polynomial, and I create an algorithm $B(G)$ which simply calls $A$ with $k = n/100$, in which framework is $B$ a polytime algorithm?

Comment: in the framework where $k$ is a fixed constant